# Maven pom.xml (disable optimization portion of build)

Tags: javascript, maven, pom.xml

Currently my pom.xml causes the js files to be minimized.  I'd like to be able to create a developer build where the js files are not minimized in order to more easily debug the js.

If I were to do this in ant I'd set a variable and then put an if expression into the element.  How do I do the equivalent in maven?

Thank you!!!

MG

Comment: What's minimizing them? We can't see your pom.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this js minimization is done by a plugin that you execute in the `<build><plugins>` part of your project's pom?

Then your requirement sounds like something that can be solved with profiles in maven. Create a profile in your pom, something like

```
<profiles>
<profile>
<id>minimize-js</id>
<build>
...
</build>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

Then move the execution of the minimizer plugin from your project's main `<build>` section into the `<build>` section of your profile. The plugin will then only be executed when you tell Maven to include that profile in your build.

So if you only run

mvn clean install

the minimize plugin won't be executed, but if you run

mvn clean install -P minimize-js

then it will trigger your plugin and minimize the js.

Comment: Thank you!  That does sound like the correct way to do it.  I typically run mvn package to do everything.  So with this in mind if I want a developer build I could create a profile called developer and then have the original js files overwrite the new minimized ones?  I'd like to keep the default package command as is.  Would that be the correct way or could I somehow tell package that I want it to run the minimize profile in addition to everything else and then have another profile which I tell to only do everything else?

Comment: <plugin>
        <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-minify-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>

Comment: For that you could have the plugin execution added to both your project's main <build> section and to the <build> section of the developer profile, but with different configuration, e.g. set the plugins "disabled" property to true or the list of compressed files to an empty value in the developer profile. The plugin config from the developer profile will then kind of replace the plugin configuration from the main <build> section if you built with that profile as long as both plugin <execution>s have the same id.